Не удается установить django в virtualenv
В VScode (вдруг это важно) я создаю виртуальную среду и пытаюсь установить django, вот последовательность действий:

virtualenv myenv
myenv\Scripts\activate
pip install django

Последняя операция не завершается сколько бы я не ждал (скриншот)

Без виртуальной среды все устанавливается отлично.

не пробовали установить виртуальное окружение через venv? команда -> py -m venv myenv.

попробовал, результат тот же

попробуйте накидать флагов, чтобы понять где затыкается установка, можно найти здесь. Например --report. Также, можно попробовать установить определенную версию django или еще забрать и установить из бинарников

Я разобрался. Ошибка возникала только в этой папке. Ранее я скопировал ее из другой директории, видимо из за этого что то сбилось. В новой папке все работает нормально

мат уберите, здесь не принято

окㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Такая проблема может возникать, когда виртуальное окружение ссылается не на подходящий файл python.exe
В качестве проверки можно сделать следующее:

Выполнить в терминале команду:

where python

Будет выведен путь Python, который расположен в системной переменной PATH.
Важно: если путь не выводится, то необходимо добавить Python в PATH, либо спуститься на уровень диска с помощью команды
cd ..

Или другим комфортным способом. После чего заново запустить команду where.

Скопировать путь, сократив его справа до директории (например: C:\Users\Somebody\Python\Python38)

Открыть файл myenv\pyvenv.cfg и напротив параметра home справа от знака равно указать путь, который ранее был скопирован.

Заново запустить виртуальное окружение

Установить модуль django при помощи команды:


python -m pip install django

